# How to find the 95% of bivariate data in r?

Tags: r

Say I have a data set:

```
structure(c(96L, 37L, 18L, 40L, 57L, 46L, 8L, 47L, 3L, 75L, 13L, 
61L, 42L, 72L, 48L, 4L, 79L, 5L, 97L, 6L), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("V1", "V2")))
```

Visualize:

```
      V1 V2
 [1,] 96 13
 [2,] 37 61
 [3,] 18 42
 [4,] 40 72
 [5,] 57 48
 [6,] 46  4
 [7,]  8 79
 [8,] 47  5
 [9,]  3 97
[10,] 75  6
```

I want to find 95% of the data. So, I want a plot with all the datapoint and some indication (like a box or cirle) that shows specifically 95% of the data. How can i do this?

Edited for comment.
95% CI of the data. For example, in 1-dimension, we can simply plot the data and find 95% data by setting alpha = 0.05
[image]

What if we increase the dimension to 2D?
In addition, assume we don't know the distribution, only the data points are given.

Comment: *"I want to find 95% of the data"* The 95% CI of *what*? The mean? Assuming an underlying bivariate *normal* distribution? Please be precise and specific. The statement "95% of the data" makes no sense statistically.

Comment: Hi @MathAvengers. Sorry, but "95% CI of the data" makes no sense. The plot you're showing seems to be some posterior density of a quantity called Q. The green area corresponds to a credible (?) interval based on the (posterior) density of Q. So this would be a 95% CI of Q, **not of "the data"**.  Coming back to your question: What is that quantity Q in your case? The mean? And what is the underlying bivariate distribution. A bivariate normal? A bivariate log-normal? A bivariate ...?

Comment: @MauritsEvers  My bad! sorry, I get what you mean now. i mean 95% of the data CI of Q (median), and the distribution is unknown, only the datapoints are given. So I don't think there's a specific distribution like Gaussian or exponential.

Comment: A CI (or credible interval) is a result of a statistical inference procedure which provides an estimate of a population parameter. A CI is *not* a statement about the data. You seem to have samples drawn from some bivariate distribution. In order to infer a CI (or credible interval) of some parameter, you need a statistical inference method estimate these parameters. This in turn also means that you need to know something about the underlying bivariate distribution. [...]

Comment: [continued] So in order for us to help you, you need to tell us (1) which parameter(s) you're trying to estimate (mean, median, ...?), and (2) what the underlying distribution is from which the samples were drawn; if the density is a posterior density, you need to give us code/data to reproduce the posterior density.

Comment: Do you seek a generalization of quantiles for bidimensional data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up from the comments, here is something that should get you started.

I use `rstan` to fit a bivariate normal distribution to the data. We obtain posterior densities for the parameters `mu` (the mean, a vector of length 2) and `Sigma` (the 2x2 covariance matrix).

Let's start by loading the necessary library and sample data.

```r
library(rstan)
df <- structure(c(96L, 37L, 18L, 40L, 57L, 46L, 8L, 47L, 3L, 75L, 13L,
61L, 42L, 72L, 48L, 4L, 79L, 5L, 97L, 6L), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("V1", "V2")))
df <- setNames(as.data.frame(df), c("x1", "x2"))
```

We now define our model

```r
model <- "
data {
    int<lower=1> N;     // Number of samples
    vector[2] y[N];     // Samples
}

parameters {
    vector[2] mu;
    cov_matrix[2] Sigma;
}

model {
    // Likelihood
    y ~ multi_normal(mu, Sigma);
}
"
```

We don't specify any priors on the parameters, which defaults to flat (uninformative) priors. Note that this is usually not a good idea; however, which priors to choose often requires domain-specific knowledge and goes beyond this little exercise. You can find more details [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/wiki/Prior-Choice-Recommendations).

Let's fit the model

```r
fit <- stan(model_code = model, data = list(N = nrow(df), y = df))
```

and extract samples from the joint posterior density for `mu`

```r
df_samples <- as.data.frame(extract(fit, "mu"))
```

We can now visualise data along with a 95% credible ellipse for the estimated mean `mu`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x1, x2)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_ellipse(data = df_fit, aes(mu.1, mu.2), colour = "orange") +
    theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Note that

1. the points denote the original data points
2. the orange ellipse denotes the 95% credible ellipse of the estimated mean parameter from a bivariate normal distribution. The ellipse contains 95% of the joint posterior density for `mu`.